# How to supress warnings from SonarLint in Eclipse without causing "Unsupported @SuppressWarnings" issue

Tags: java, eclipse, suppress-warnings, sonarlint

I am using SonarLint (SonarLint for Eclipse 7.7.0.60863) with Eclipse (Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)) and it shows warnings like "Server certificates should be verified during SSL/TLS connections (java:S4830)". Since I am handling this issue (it is just for dev environment) I want to suppress this warning. So I **added @SuppressWarnings({"java:S4830"})** annotation to method as this is a suggested as optimal solution ( Instead of //NOSONAR ignoring all sonar warnings in line).

**SonarLint warning disappeared but now I have new warning "Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("java:S4830")"**

Original code:

[image: Original code with SonarLint warning]

After ignoring SonarLint issue:

[image: Code with suppressed SonarLint issue]

Code to reproduce issue:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"java:S4830"})
    private void setSslToTrustAll() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        X509TrustManager trustAllManager = new X509TrustManager() {
            
            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
            
            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType){
                // trust all
            }
            
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType){
                // trust all
            }
        };
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[] {trustAllManager};
        SSLContext sslContect = SSLContext.getDefault();
        sslContect.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContect.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);
    }
```

I do not want to use //NOSONAR to disable all warnings.
I tried to use different names like @SuppressWarnings({"squid:S4830"}) - this also removes SonarLint warning but "Unsupported @SuppressWarnings" appears.

Comment: What about disabling the rule in your IDE?

Comment: In your second screenshot, click on _Configure problem severity_ and set it to _Ignore_.

Comment: @dan1st If it would be possible to disable for one project that could do, but disabling it for whole workspace or all projects seems risky. But I do not see such options . I see there are SonarLint "Analyzer Properties" configurable for project, so maybe there are properties to configure to ignore it.

Comment: You can disable the warning for just one project - "Java Compiler" > "Errors/Warnings", Annotations section in the project Properties

Comment: Yeah that could work for me if nothing better appears. But it is just a workaround. My intention is not to suppress all "Unsupported @SuppressWarnings" but to suppress specific SonarLint warning (without causing others). Feel free to add this as answer but I will not accept it.

Comment: It sounds like `//NOSONAR` for this class only would be sufficient. Since it's mostly empty and only for dev environment anyway, I don't see a big risk of missing other warnings. But it sounds like you are looking for a more granular solution.

Comment: Setting _Unhandled token in '@SupressWarnings'_ to _Ignore_ is exactly for your use case and not a workaround. _Unhandled_ means here unhandled by the Eclipse Java compiler (it's a compiler setting!). You still will get problem markers for e.g. `@SuppressWarnings({"unused"})` for something that is used.

Comment: Also: if you use SonarQube (and not just SonarLint), then you can actually set an individual warning as a false positive on the web UI, one of the advantages of having a central server.

Comment: @howlger I see what you mean. Please add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ***Configure problem severity*** quick fix link (shown in your second screenshot) to go to the Java compiler settings and **set *Unhandled token in '@SupressWarnings'* to *Ignore***.

Even by ignoring `@SuppressWarnings` tokens that are not known to the Java compiler, problems for `@SuppressWarnings` tokens that are known to the Java compiler will still be displayed, such as for a superfluous `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` at something that is used or not private.